# Getting no signal when using using DP to HDMI adapter

Tags: hdmi, displayport, display-adapter

I bought 2 adapters like [this](https://www.vention.cn/product/dp-to-hdmi-adapter-2/) because I have 2 monitors that accept HDMI input and a [Thunderbolt docking station](https://www.startech.com/en-us/cards-adapters/tb3cdk2dp) that only has DP output.

However, when I connect my monitor using the adapters that I bought, I get no signal.

Can someone help me troubleshoot this?

P.S., Both the monitors and the cables I use are tested to be working. I do not have other adapters to test with and I do not have another docking station.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adapters you give as examples are passive, they require that the source provide the HDMI signal.  It's quite common for a DisplayPort output to be backward compatible with HDMI, and this is often noted with a DP++ icon next to the port as opposed to a DP icon (lacking the "++").  DisplayPort outputs without HDMI backward compatibility will require an active adapter to get an HDMI output, like this one:  https://www.startech.com/en-us/audio-video-products/dp2hd4k60h

Comment: Thanks. I thought this adapter is an active one, because of the chip. How did you identify that it is not? In other words, what was your hint or the keyword?

Comment: The chip is a level shifter, it pumps up the 3.3V from DP to 5V for HDMI.  I identified it as a passive adapter by seeing no mention of it being an active adapter in the advert copy.  Oh, and by it not working for you.  An active adapter is far more complex and expensive, if it's an active adapter then they are going to tell you somewhere.  The dock user manual says that HDMI displays will require an active adapter, another clue on the adapters being passive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.